# C++ - virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, sdl, virtual, abstract

First of all I want to say that I originally learnt C++ with the C++ Primer, but because I wanted to learn something about the SDL lib I decided to get the "SDL-Game-Development" Book from Shaun Mitchell.

I'm now in chapter 3 and I have some problems with virtual inheritance. I know how it works but I cant find the problem in my programm.

The error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Documents\test - Kopie (2)\game.cpp||In member function 'void  Game::render()':|
C:\Users\Documents\test - Kopie (2)\game.cpp|78|error: no matching function for call to 'GameObject::draw(SDL_Renderer*&)'|
C:\Users\Documents\test - Kopie (2)\game.cpp|78|note: candidate is:|
C:\Users\Documents\test - Kopie (2)\GameObject.h|11|note: virtual void  GameObject::draw()|
C:\Users\Documents\test - Kopie (2)\GameObject.h|11|note:   candidate  expects 0 arguments, 1 provided|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I know that I have an argument too much but the Gameobject has 2 derived classes, the player class and the enemy class. The enemy class needs an argument but the player class doesn't. So when I delete the argument the builder gives me even more errors.

I will list all the Code here:

game.h:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

class Game
{
public:

bool init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, int flags);
void render();
void update();
void handleEvents();
void clean();
bool running() { return m_bRunning; }
SDL_Renderer* getRenderer() const { return m_pRenderer; }
std::vector<GameObject*> m_gameObjects;

static Game* Instance()
{
if(s_pInstance == 0)
{
s_pInstance = new Game();
return s_pInstance;
}
return s_pInstance;
}

private:
Game() {}

bool m_bRunning;
SDL_Window* m_pWindow;
SDL_Renderer* m_pRenderer;
SDL_Texture* m_pTexture; // the new SDL_Texture variable
int m_currentFrame;
GameObject* m_go;
GameObject* m_player;
GameObject* m_enemy;
static Game* s_pInstance;

};
```

game.cpp:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "game.h"
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool Game::init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width,
int height, int flags)
{
// attempt to initialize SDL
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
{

m_gameObjects.push_back(new Player(new LoaderParams(100, 100, 128, 82, "animate")));
m_gameObjects.push_back(new Enemy(new LoaderParams(300, 300, 128, 82, "animate")));

cout << "SDL init success\n";
// init the window
m_pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
if(m_pWindow != 0) // window init success
{
cout << "window creation success\n";
m_pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_pWindow, -1, 0);
if(m_pRenderer != 0) // renderer init success
{
cout << "renderer creation success\n";
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_pRenderer, 255,0,0,255);

if(!TextureManager::Instance()->load("explosion-sprite.png", "animate", m_pRenderer))
{
return false;
}

}
else
{
cout << "renderer init fail\n";
return false; // renderer init fail
}
}
else
{
cout << "window init fail\n";
return false; // window init fail
}
}
else
{
cout << "SDL init fail\n";
return false; // SDL init fail
}
cout << "init success\n";
m_bRunning = true; // everything inited successfully,
return true;
}

void Game::render()
{
SDL_RenderClear(m_pRenderer); // clear the renderer to

for(std::vector<GameObject*>::size_type i = 0; i != m_gameObjects.size(); i++)
{
m_gameObjects[i]->draw(m_pRenderer);
}

SDL_RenderPresent(m_pRenderer); // draw to the screen
}

void Game::handleEvents(){
SDL_Event event;
if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
switch (event.type){
case SDL_QUIT:
m_bRunning = false;
break;
default:
break;
    }
}
}

void Game::clean(){
cout << "cleaning game\n";
SDL_DestroyWindow(m_pWindow);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_pRenderer);
SDL_Quit();
}

void Game::update()
{
for(std::vector<GameObject*>::size_type i = 0; i !=
m_gameObjects.size(); i++)
{
m_gameObjects[i]->update();
}
}

Game* Game::s_pInstance = 0;
```

TextureManager.h:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "Loaderparams.h"

using namespace std;

class TextureManager{
public:
bool load(string filename, string id, SDL_Renderer* Renderer);

void draw(string id, int x, int y, int width, int height, SDL_Renderer* Renderer, SDL_RendererFlip = SDL_FLIP_NONE);

void drawFrame(string id, int x, int y, int width, int height, int row, int frame, SDL_Renderer* Renderer, SDL_RendererFlip flip = SDL_FLIP_NONE);

static TextureManager* Instance();

private:
TextureManager() {}
map<string, SDL_Texture*> textureMap;
};
```

TextureManager.cpp:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include <SDL_image.h>

using namespace std;

bool TextureManager::load(string filename, string id, SDL_Renderer* Renderer){
SDL_Surface* surf = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());

if(surf == NULL)
return false;

SDL_Texture* text = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Renderer, surf);
SDL_FreeSurface(surf);

if(text != 0){
textureMap[id] = text;
return true;
}
return false;
}



void TextureManager::draw(string id, int x, int y, int width, int height, SDL_Renderer* Renderer, SDL_RendererFlip flip){

SDL_Rect source;
SDL_Rect destination;

source.x = 0;
source.y = 0;
destination.w = source.w = width;
destination.h = source.h = height;

destination.x = x;
destination.y = y;

SDL_RenderCopyEx(Renderer, textureMap[id], &source, &destination, 0, 0, flip);
}



void TextureManager::drawFrame(string id, int x, int y, int width, int height, int row, int frame, SDL_Renderer* Renderer, SDL_RendererFlip flip){

SDL_Rect source;
SDL_Rect destination;

source.x = width * frame;
source.y = height * row;

destination.w = source.w = width;
destination.h = source.h = height;

destination.x = x;
destination.y = y;

SDL_RenderCopyEx(Renderer, textureMap[id], &source, &destination, 0, 0, flip);
}

TextureManager* s_pInstance = 0;

TextureManager* TextureManager::Instance(){
    if(s_pInstance == 0){
        s_pInstance = new TextureManager();
        return s_pInstance;
    }
    return s_pInstance;
}
```

player.h:

```
#include "GameObject.h"

using namespace std;

class Player : public SDLGameObject
{
public:
Player(const LoaderParams* pParams): SDLGameObject(pParams){}

virtual void draw();
virtual void update();
virtual void clean();
};

// Enemy class
class Enemy : public SDLGameObject
{
public:
Enemy(const LoaderParams* pParams);
virtual void draw();
virtual void update();
virtual void clean();
};
```

player.cpp:

```
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

void Player::load(int x, int y, int width, int height, string textureID)
{
GameObject::load(x, y, width, height, textureID);
}


void Player::draw()
{
SDLGameObject::draw(); // we now use SDLGameObject
}


void Player::update()
{
m_x -= 1;
m_currentFrame = int(((SDL_GetTicks() / 100) % 6));
}

void Player::clean() {}

//ENEMY

void Enemy::load(int x, int y, int width, int height, string
textureID)
{
GameObject::load(x, y, width, height, textureID);
}


void Enemy::draw(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
{
GameObject::draw(pRenderer);
}


void Enemy::update()
{
m_position.setX(m_position.getX() + 1);
m_position.setY(m_position.getY() + 1);
m_currentFrame = int(((SDL_GetTicks() / 100) % 6));
}

void Enemy::clean(){
}
```

Gameobject.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include "Vector2D.h"

using namespace std;

class GameObject
{
public:
virtual void draw() = 0;
virtual void update() = 0;
virtual void clean() = 0;
protected:
GameObject(const LoaderParams* pParams) {}
virtual ~GameObject() {}
};


class SDLGameObject : public GameObject
{
public:
SDLGameObject(const LoaderParams* pParams) :
GameObject(pParams), m_position(pParams->getX(), pParams->getY())
{
m_width = pParams->getWidth();
m_height = pParams->getHeight();
m_textureID = pParams->getTextureID();
m_currentRow = 1;
m_currentFrame = 1;
}

virtual void draw();
virtual void update();
virtual void clean();
protected:
Vector2D m_position;
int m_width;
int m_height;
int m_currentRow;
int m_currentFrame;
std::string m_textureID;
};
```

Gameobject.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "GameObject.h"

using namespace std;

void GameObject::draw(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
{
TextureManager::Instance()->drawFrame(m_textureID, m_x, m_y,
m_width, m_height, m_currentRow, m_currentFrame, pRenderer);
}


void GameObject::update()
{
m_x += 1;
}

void GameObject::clean(){
}


//SDLGameObject

void SDLGameObject::draw()
{
TextureManager::Instance()->drawFrame(m_textureID,
(int)m_position.getX(), (int)m_position.getY(), m_width,
m_height, m_currentRow, m_currentFrame,
Game::Instance()->getRenderer());
}
```

There's also a Vector.h but it's not importent for the problem

Comment: Please indent your code. Nobody is going to read through this headache.

Comment: I'm quite sure that 95% of that code could be removed without affecting the problem. That would make it much more likely that people will read it, and it might even lead to discovering what's wrong on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
class GameObject
{

    public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void clean() = 0;
    protected:
    GameObject(const LoaderParams* pParams) {}
    virtual ~GameObject() {}

};
```

only have a `draw()`

so you can't do `m_gameObjects[i]->draw(m_pRenderer);`

The signature doesn't match. The `GameObject` class only have a `draw()`.

Remember that you can't change the function signature of a virtual function by inheritance. The signature must stay the same.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should add overloaded method signature in header file too.

```
virtual void draw();
virtual void draw(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer);
```

I didn't check the whole code so there might be other issues, but that particular error message indicates that the `draw` method with that signature does not exists.

Remember that `cpp` files will be compiled into object files and linker is the one who knows that method exists, that's why complier that doesn't have any information about that overloaded method complains about inappropriate signature.

Answer (score -1):

I also follow this book now. This is at the end of the 3-rd chapter of the book where the `GameObject` class is refactored to be abstract class and `SDLGameObject` is introduced as it's offspring having `SDL` specific interface. Also Game class is refactored to be a singleton. The error occur because in new version in `SDLGameObject` and it's descendants (`Player, Enemy`) the `SDL` `renderer` is not passed to their methods as parameter any more. Instead, it's accessed through Game singleton object like this`Game::Instance()->getRenderer()`. Even after making all changes the animated images refused to show up in the window! Until I figured out that no one calls `TextureManager` to load the image from the file. I've added the new field `fileName` and it's corresponding getter to the class `LoaderParams` and added the following code to the constructor of `SDLGameObject` class:

```
TextureManager::Instance()->load(pParams->getFileName(), m_textureID, TheGame::Instance()->getRenderer());
```

Those who follow the book be aware!